# How to change radio's inactive color in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, radio-button

I have a `Radio` button inside a `ListTile`. When the `ListTile` is clicked, I change the `Radio`'s value. I don't want the radio to be clickable, so I don't provide an `onChanged` callback:

```
ListTile(
  onTap: () => onChanged(template.id),
  leading: Radio(
    value: template.id,
    groupValue: checkedId,
  )
  ...
)
```

Doing that, the `Radio` becomes "inactive" and changes it's color to grey.
The `Radio` has an `activeColor` property, but not for inactive.

If I provide a dummy function to `Radio`'s `onChanged` property - it becomes active, but the problem is I don't want it to be clickable, I want the `ListTile` to be clickable only (the reason is - I want to be able to uncheck the `Radio`)

Also, I only want to change the inactive color of those specific `Radio` buttons, and not for the whole app.

Current Result:

[image: Demo 1]

Result with `onChange` (I can't uncheck the radio when clicking on it):

[image: Demo 2]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Radio` uses `unselectedWidgetColor` of `ThemeData`. If you need to change it only for a few radios on a specific screen, wrap them in `Theme` widget to override a color:

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.red,
    disabledColor: Colors.blue
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        onTap: () => setState(() => value = 0),
        leading: Radio(
          value: 0,
          groupValue: value,
          onChanged: (v) => setState(() => value = v),
        )
      ),
      ListTile(
        onTap: () => setState(() => value = 1),
        leading: Radio(
          value: 1,
          groupValue: value,
          onChanged: (v) => setState(() => value = v),
        )
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

If no callback passed in `onChanged` to `Radio`, it is interpreted as disabled (this works for many default material widgets).

Comment: This will make the `Radio` blue also when not selected. The following will fix this: `disabledColor: template.ai == checkedAi ? Colors.blue : null,` Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to change radio background color? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166407/flutter-how-to-change-radio-background-color/64167054?noredirect=1#comment113470539_64167054

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the `fillColor` propery, it resolves a color for multiple radio states. In this case, it returns `Colors.blue` for all states.

```
Radio(
          fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue),
          value: 1,
          groupValue: _optionValue,
          onChanged: changeValue,
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the most flexible answer:

```
fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
              // active
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                return Colors.blue;
              }
              // inactive
              return Colors.grey.shade600;
            }),
```

You can control many different states ([MaterialState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialState.html)).

Answer (score -1):

To change the radio unselected color:

```
unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.green,
```

To change radio selected color:

```
toggleableActiveColor: Colors.green,
```

Comment: Please provide complete example of the code you are providing