# Flutter - how to change radio background color

Tags: flutter, background, radio-button, styles

Flutter Radio background is transparent by default, is it possible to change it?

[image]

I can wrap with container and set background container color. However, the radio has a padding for hover color, so there is a padding between container background and radio button. I can hardcode container size but it is not good solution.

```
Container(
              width: 20,
              height: 20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange, shape: BoxShape.circle),
              child: Theme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                      unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white
                  ),
                  child: Radio(
                      value: gender,
                      activeColor: Colors.white,
                      groupValue: _gender,
                      onChanged: (Gender value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _gender = value;
                        });
                      }))),
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?  Same issue, no answers here work.

Comment: [It seems you have to create a custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68243353/3935156)

Answer (score 1):

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.red,
    disabledColor: Colors.blue
  ),
  Radio(
                      value: gender,
                      activeColor: Colors.white,
                      groupValue: _gender,
                      onChanged: (Gender value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _gender = value;
                        });
                      }),
)
```

you have to give `disabledColor`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I want to change background of both selected and unselected radio buttons

Comment: I guess `disabledColor` is doing for you

Answer (score 0):

```
Theme(
       data: ThemeData(
       toggleableActiveColor: Colors.red,
       unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey),
     child: Radio(`enter code here)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.